# How to Undo a rails destroy controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy, undo

I was trying to delete two pages from my files (pages/about & pages/contact) and I used the terminal line:

```
rails destroy controller pages about contact
```

This command did delete them, but it also deleted my entire app/views/pages folder which included the home page and more!
Unfortunately I did not upload to github.

Is there a way to undo a "Rails destroy" and recover the lost files?

Comment: use `git` to revert the changes. Or simply `rails g controller pages about contact` but this will not recover the code you've lost

Comment: check your recycle bin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once controller is destroyed using `rails destroy controller ...` command, it can't be undone.

Be sure that you've version controlled your code using git or similar VCS tools. If your code is on git then you can easily get all deleted files back.

```
git checkout app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
```